# GeoTrellis/Scala: Locate missing implicit evidence for Json Parsing

Tags: scala, implicit, spray-json, geotrellis

What imports are needed to locate the implicit evidence to compile a call to GeoJson.parse from GeoTrellis?

geotrellis.vector.io.json.Geometry uses spray.json to parse, and must be able to locate a JsonReader or JsonFormats instance, templated to WithCrs and Geometry classes.

The evidence is defined within FeatureFormats; but how can the snippet below use it?

The following does not resolve the evidence:

1. Import everything in the `geotrellis.vector.io.json.*` package
2. Import the Implicits specifically `import geotrellis.vector.io.json.Implicits`
3. Import FeatureFormats directly `import geotrellis.vector.io.json.FeatureFormats`
4. Ensure the correct imports, especially no imports of `com.vividsolutions.jts.Geometry` which would mask the target object

Here's the code in question

```
import geotrellis.vector.Geometry
import geotrellis.proj4.CRS
import geotrellis.vector.io.json.*
import geotrellis.vector.io.json.{GeoJson, WithCrs}
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}
val exampleQueryJson =
  """
|{
|   "type": "Polygon",
|   "crs": {
|       "type": "name",
|       "properties": {
|           "name": "EPSG:4326"
|       }
|   },
|   "coordinates": [
|       [
|           [....]
|       ]
|   ]
|}
  """.stripMargin

class GeometryReader extends FeatureFormats {
  implicit val jsonFormats: Formats = DefaultFormats
}

object GeometryReader {

  def parseGeometry(request: String): Geometry = {

    GeoJson.parse[Geometry](request)
  }
}

val g = GeometryReader.parseGeometry(exampleQueryJson)
```

The compile error shows the inability to find the right evidence given what's currently available

```
[error] /path/redacted/GeometryReader.scala:19: Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for geotrellis.vector.io.json.WithCrs[geotrellis.vector.Geometry]
[error]       val geometryWithCrs: WithCrs[Geometry] = GeoJson.parse[WithCrs[Geometry]](request)
[error]                                                                                ^
[error] /path/redacted/GeometryReader.scala:25: Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for geotrellis.vector.Geometry
[error]       Try(GeoJson.parse[Geometry](request)) match {
[error]                                  ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Comment: Your description says `spray-json` but your code snippet has `org.json4s`. Those are 2 completely different libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Add

`import geotrellis.vector.io._`

The creators of this library made use of package objects to publish these implicits. The package object (source code below) extends g.io.json.Implicits, and that brings them into scope.

https://github.com/locationtech/geotrellis/blob/master/vector/src/main/scala/geotrellis/vector/io/package.scala

More about package objects:

https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html